# EF Core 2.0 Migration - dotnet ef migrations 'script' command outputting blank file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have recently migrated my web project to Asp.Net Core 2.0 and Entity Framework Core 2.0.

The web application is working correctly and all dotnet ef migrations CLI commands are working apart from the following:

```
dotnet ef migrations script {migrationname1} {migrationname1} -o my-file-name.sql
```

The query appears to run with no errors and then produces no SQL code either to screen or file.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with SQL Server Express (localdb) on Windows.

Just wondering if anyone else has come across the issue since migrating?

Would appreciate some help as can not find anything on here or Google.

Comment: Do you get more info if you add the `-v` (verbose) option?

Comment: Thanks Steve - I used verbose to get more info, and after lots of investigation work - including converting my project to a new .NET Standard Class library and then back again - it looks very much like this is a bug with EF Core 2.0 Tools.

Answer (score 8):

After lots of wasted effort and time, it looks like this is a bug with `dotnet ef migrations script`, as this is not functioning as it did in EF Core 1.0.

```
Script-Migration -From 20171106124427_061120171243
```

Outputs blank

```
Script-Migration -From 20171106124427_061120171243 -To 20171106124427_061120171243
```

Outputs blank (note the -From and -To values are the same)

```
Script-Migration 20171106124427_061120171243
```

Outputs blank

```
Script-Migration -From 20171106122611_061120171225 -To 20171106124427_061120171243
```

Outputs SQL statements as expected (Note -From and -To values are different)

I get the same results whether I try this in Visual Studio 2017 Package Manager Console or the CLI.

After further investigation it would appear the answer lies in the following:

```
Script-Migration -From <PreviousMigration> -To <LastMigration>
```

It would appear that it is my misunderstanding of the -From and -To attributes that is the problem regardless of whether this used to work in a previous version.

I had incorrectly assumed that the -From migration file would be included in the resulting code generation, but after some testing this does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 7):

E. Gads.  LOL

I have come up with the answer and it is so ridiculous.

Here is the syntax you use to add a migration:

```
Add-Migration MigrationName -Context MyDbContext
```

Because I like to save time I up arrow and down arrow in the Package Manager Console to recall previous commands.  If you recall the command and change Add-Migration to Script-Migration you will end up runnig:

```
Script-Migration MigrationName -Context MyDbContext
```

This will end up silently failing and opening up an empty SQL file!  Drat!

This is the command you want to run:

```
Script-Migration -Context MyDbContext
```

Then it will work.  If this is not your problem, sorry.  I found that adding the `-v` option to the command is quite revealing and I would suggest that you try it.

### EDIT:

Above are PowerShell commands for the Package Manager Console.  The answer by @Suraj is helpful if you are using `dotnet ef migrations` from the command line.  (You need to use the **FROM** and **TO** arguments).

Comment: I should note that I have multiple DbContexts which is why I need to specify the `-Context` argument.  You might not need that.

Answer (score 5):

```
dotnet ef migrations script FromA FromB
```

This will get the script generated in the terminal itself

If  you want to generate to a file use this option

```
dotnet ef migrations script FromA FromB -o sample.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are creating your initial Script-Migration then leave the migration name blank. Leaving the migration name blank will also script the entire database.

So, for example, this will return a blank sql file in a project with one migration named InitialCreate:

`Script-Migration InitialCreate`

While this would return the correct sql file:

`Script-Migration`